# How to set viewport property in google maps MapOptions v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using [google.maps.Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder) to get [viewport](http://google.maps.GeocoderGeometry). Then I want to create google.maps.Map so the map will fit this viewport. There is a method fitBounds. It works perfectly. But it's better to specify viewport in constructor. I can't find this option in [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set it in the constructor, other than by calculating an exact map width, heighth and zoom level, but zoom levels are discrete values, so it might not be the exact fit that you want.

If you create the map and apply [map.fitBounds()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.fitBounds) immediately after that, it all happens so fast that it is perfectly transparent to the user.